# Query .evtx converted to .xml

Tags: basex, xquery-3.0

Having used evtx_dump.py to convert .evtx files to .xml i seek to learn how to query it using XQuery or whatever helps me datamine the document using BaseX.

At this point whatever i try i can only query the whole document using //Events

When i define a path such as //Events/Event/System/[EventID = '4688'] i get 0 results.

This first query is to simply track all specific EventID matching a specific value.

Being new to BaseX and XQuery i found the documentation hard to apply to this use case.

I looked for tools to help me build an XQuery to no avail.

BaseX has all index features enabled  i could find.

Br,

Joris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When XQuery fails to return data you are expecting it is often caused by the presence XML namespaces.

The Microsoft XML event log uses a XML namespace on Event nodes and it is inherited by their children. This is the `xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'` you can see in the files. E.g

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Events><Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
   <System><Provider Name='SideBySide'/><EventID Qualifiers='49409'>59</EventID><Version>0</Version>
    ...
```

Your XQuery must adjust for that. Either by saying any namespace is ok (using `*:`)

```
//*:System/[*:EventID = '4688']
```

or by explicitly specifing the expected namespaces.

```
declare namespace ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event";
/Events/ns:Event/ns:System[ns:EventID= '4688' ]
```

See this similar issue [xquery-not-working-with-namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682386/xquery-not-working-with-namespaces)

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what i needed.  
It would have taken me weeks to find this out myself.  
  
This XQuery works as expected to list all EventID  

`for $e in //*:Events/*:Event/*:System/*:EventID  
return $e`